# How do I install rar in a Alpine based container?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, rar

A program in the container needs `rar` (in addition to `unrar`), I used the following commands to install it to `/usr/bin`:

```
curl https://www.rarlab.com/rar/rarlinux-x64-6.0.b1.tar.gz | tar -xzvf - -C /tmp/
cp -rfp /tmp/rar/rar /usr/bin/rar
```

Now `/usr/bin/rar` exist and has 755 permission, and `/usr/bin` is in `$PATH`, but when I run `rar -v` or `/usr/bin/rar`, it outputs `ash: rar: not found` and `ash: /usr/bin/rar: not found` respectively.

I got the same result with `make` and `make install` in `/tmp/rar` which after it copy `rar` and `unrar` into `/usr/local/bin`, which is also in `$PATH`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpine is built using [musl-libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/). Software compiled against the more common [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) will often not run in this environment because it can't find the expected dynamic loader.

Common ways to solve this include either (a) compile the code yourself or (b) install a version that has been built elsewhere for Alpine. I don't believe either of these is going to be an option for Rar.

Your best bet is just to replace Alpine as your base image with something (really, almost anything) else (debian, ubuntu, fedora, centos, etc).

(Note that if you just need to extract Rar archives, you can simply `apk add unrar` under Alpine).

Comment: FYI: "install" is not an apk command (did you mean "add"?) and unrar doesn't exist in the Alpine repositories anyway.

Comment: Good catch re: add vs install, and at the time this was written there was an `unrar` package available.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alpine image in dockerhub with a functional rar version 5.4 in alpine. So you could just copy it in your image.

You could do this in your Dockerfile

```
FROM klutchell/rar as rar
COPY --from=rar /usr/local/bin/rar /usr/local/bin/rar
```